# Tensorflow - numpy gradient check doesnt work

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, mnist, adversarial-machines

I'm trying to estimate the gradient of a function by the finite difference method :
[finite difference method for estimating gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)

TLDR:

`grad f(x) = [f(x+h)-f(x-h)]/(2h)` for sufficiently small h.

this is also used in the gradient check phase to check your backpropagation in AI as you might know.

This is my network :

```
def defineModel():
  global model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(keras.Input(shape=input_shape))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add( layers.Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))
  model.build()
  model.summary()
```

This part is fine and has no bugs. I just mentioned it here so you have a sense of my model. I work on MNIST so everything is pretty straightforward. With 1 epoch and a few lines of the TF code, I reached +98% accuracy which is quite good for a makeshift model.

Since I'm doing adversarial training, I want the gradient of my loss with respect to the input data:

**by the way, I used the tiling idea:**

if you cover the input image with square tiles of (tile*tile) dimension with no overlapping, you can assume the gradient of the image within tiles is pretty much constant so it's a reasonable approximation. But as a matter of debugging, in my code `tile=1` so we're calculating the pixel-wise gradient.

and this is where the problem lies, but I cannot figure out where! I controlled the loss for `loss(x+h)` and `loss(x-h)` and `loss(x)` are pretty much in a close range so I know it is fine. also my TF automatic backpropagation works fine I have tested it. the problem must be with the way of computing manual gradient.

```
tile=1
h=1e-4 #also tried 1e-5, 1e-6 but did not work

#A dummy function to wait
def w():
  print()
  ww=input('wait')
  print()

#This function works fine.
def rel_error(x, y):
  """ returns relative error """
  return np.max(np.abs(x - y) / (np.maximum(1e-8, np.abs(x) + np.abs(y))))

#the problem is here. given an index suah is idx, I'm going to manipulate
#x_test[idx] and compute loss gradient with respect to this input
def estimateGrad(idx):
  y=model(np.expand_dims(x_test[idx],axis=0))
  y=np.expand_dims(y_train[idx],axis=0)
  x=np.squeeze(x_test[idx])

  

  cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
  grad=np.zeros((28,28))
  num=int(28/tile)

  #MNIST pictures are 28*28 pixels. Now grad is 28*28 nd.array
  #and x is input image converted to 28*28 nd.array
  for i in range(num):
    for j in range(num):

      plus=copy.deepcopy(x)
      minus=copy.deepcopy(x)
      #Now plus is x+h and minus is x-h
      plus[i*tile:(i+1)*tile , j*tile:(j+1)*tile]=  plus[i*tile:(i+1)*tile , j*tile:(j+1)*tile]+h
      minus[i*tile:(i+1)*tile , j*tile:(j+1)*tile]=  minus[i*tile:(i+1)*tile , j*tile:(j+1)*tile]-h

       
      plus=np.expand_dims(plus,axis=(0,-1))
      minus=np.expand_dims(minus,axis=(0,-1))

      #Now we pass plus and minus to model prediction in the next two lines
      plus=model(plus)
      minus=model(minus)
      
      #Since I want to find gradient of loss with respect to x, in the next 
      #two lines I will set plus=loss(x+h) and minus=loss(x-h)
      #In other words, here our finction f which we want to cumpute its grads
      #is the loss function

      plus=cce(y,plus).numpy()
      minus=cce(y,minus).numpy()

      #Applying the formola : grad=(loss(x+h)-loss(x-h))/2/h
      grad[i*tile:(i+1)*tile , j*tile:(j+1)*tile]=(plus-minus)/2/h

 #Ok now lets check our grad with TF autograd module
  x= tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(x_test[idx], axis=0)) 
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(x) 
    y=model(x)
    y_expanded=np.expand_dims(y_train[idx],axis=0)  
    loss=cce(y_expanded,y)

     
  
  delta=tape.gradient(loss,x)
  delta=delta.numpy()
  delta=np.squeeze(delta)

  #delta is gradients returned by TF via auto-differentiation.
  #We calculate the error and unfortunately its large
  diff=rel_error(grad,delta)

  print('diff ',diff)
  w()
  #problem : diff is very large. it should be less than 1e-4
```

you can refer [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bFYs9r6jkw/) for my full code.

Comment: Tip: try to condense your problem down as much as possible. If you want to know how a gradient is written, ask exactly that. Including Tensorflow shrinks the number of SO unsers that could answer your question significantly.

Comment: @AlexNe You meant users by users? unfortunately, I need to include TF because the gradients it returns is the ground truth of the gradients I should compute. That's how I calculate errors.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. But some times, we just get bogged down with our own code. Reducing complexity is almost always a good way to fix problems. Here your loss is just another hopefully differentiable function from R^n -> R, so why not simplify.... Edit: Yes, I meant users. My German iPhone seems to have swallowed  r/ich_iel.

Comment: @AlexNe Thanks, but how could I further simplify it? given that tile=1 and I'm doing pixelwise differentiation, I cannot think of any further simplification. I just added some more comments. please tell me if there could be a further simplification. maybe just removing the tiles for now?

Comment: Hmmm. I’d put gradient into its own function like my answer below. Then test it with a bunch of simple functions you know the explicit derivative. Then test with cce. Even if your code is correct, cce might not be smooth on the the scale of your h. Then computing gradients would be basically meaningless.

Comment: @AlexNe But how could loss be smooth? I trained my original network on cce (you can see it in my code) and within 1 epoch it has +98% accuracy. Since I'm doing a convex optimization ( approximating a non-convex function as a convex function) and getting a good results, I think it's not possible that cce is not differentible. Otherwise, our model could not be trained and achieve high accuary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the gradient estimation code with my own solution `gradient` and the code works now. Calculating errors can be tricky. As on can see on the histogram (note the log-scale) at the bottom, for most pixels the relative error is smaller than `10^-4` but where the gradient is close to zero, the relative error explodes.
The problem with `max(rel_err)` and `mean(rel_err)` is, that they are both easily perturbed by outlier pixels. Better measures for if the order of magnitude is most relevant are the geometric mean and median over all non-zero pixels.

#### Imports

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import copy
```

#### Gradient

```
# Gradient
def gradient(f, x, h, **kwargs):
    shape = x.shape    
    x = x.ravel()
    out = np.zeros_like(x)
    hs = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i, _ in enumerate(x):
        hs *= 0.
        hs[i] = h
        out[i] = (f((x + hs).reshape(shape), **kwargs) - f((x - hs).reshape(shape), **kwargs)) / (2*h)

    return out.reshape(shape)
```

#### Model definition etc.

Not my code.

```
x_train=y_train=x_test=y_test=None
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
batch_size= 128
epochs=1
h=1e-4
epsilon=1e-3
tile=1

model=None

def testImage(clean_img,adv_image,truth,pred):

    # image = np.squeeze(x_test[index])
    # # plot the sample
    # fig = plt.figure
    # plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    # plt.show()

    # x= np.expand_dims(x_test[index], axis=0)
    # y=model(x)
    # print('model prediction clean example : ',np.argmax(y))
    # print('the ground truth : ',y_train[index])

    print("clean image : \n")
    fig=plt.figure
    plt.imshow(clean_img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

    print("adv image : \n")
    fig=plt.figure
    plt.imshow(adv_image, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

    print('model prediction was : ',pred)
    print('truth was :',truth)

    print('\n\n')


def prepareDataset():
    global x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
    x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
    x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes) 


def defineModel():
    global model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.Input(shape=input_shape))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add( layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))
    model.build()
    model.summary()


def trainModel():
    global model
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)


def evalModel():
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("Test loss:", score[0])
    print("Test accuracy:", score[1])

def fgsm(epsilon,index):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(x_test[index], axis=0)) 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)

        cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
        y = model(x)
        y_expanded = np.expand_dims(y_train[index],axis=0)
        #y=np.squeeze(tf.transpose(y))
        loss = cce(y_expanded,y)
        delta = tape.gradient(loss,x)   
        perturbation=epsilon*tf.math.sign(delta)
        return perturbation


def w():
    print()
    ww=input('wait')
    print()


def rel_error(x, y):
    """ returns relative error """
    return np.max(np.abs(x - y) / (np.maximum(1e-8, np.abs(x) + np.abs(y))))
```

#### Estimate the Gradient

```
def estimateGrad(idx):

    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

    x = x_test[idx]
    y = y_test[idx]

    def f(x, y):
        y_pred = model(np.expand_dims(x,axis=0))
        return cce(y, y_pred[0])

    grad = gradient(f, x, 1e-3, y=y)

    tfx = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)) 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(tfx) 
        y_pred = model(tfx)
        loss=cce(y, y_pred[0])

        delta = tape.gradient(loss, tfx)
        delta = delta.numpy()
        delta = np.squeeze(delta)

    return grad, delta
```

#### Call everything

So technically this works. Unfortunately `h < 1/1000` runs into numerical issues, so this is the best we can achieve with finite differences.

```
prepareDataset()
trainModel()
grad, delta = estimateGrad(2)
abs_err = abs(delta - grad).max()
rel_err = (abs(delta - grad / np.clip(delta, 1e-8, np.infty)))

print('Absolute Error: ', abs_err)
print('Median Relative Error: ', np.median(rel_err))
print('Mean Relative Error: ', np.mean(rel_err))
print('Geometric Mean Relative Error: ', gmean(rel_err[rel_err > 0].ravel()))
print('Max Relative Error: ', np.max(rel_err))   

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(20, 5))

ax[0].imshow(grad)
ax[0].set_title('Discrete gradient')

ax[1].imshow(delta)
ax[1].set_title('Analytic gradient')

ax[1].set_title('Relative errorr')
ax[2].imshow(rel_err + 1)

ax[3].set_title('Histogram log-relative error')
logbins = np.geomspace(1e-8, rel_err.max() + 1, 8)
ax[3].hist(rel_err, bins=logbins)
ax[3].set_xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Absolute Error:  0.0001446546
Median Relative Error:  8.748577e-06
Mean Relative Error:  1781.9397
Geometric Mean Relative Error:  0.009761388
Max Relative Error:  53676.195
```

[image: Error analysis]